MQTT library does not accept network config from JSON file
My ESP32 project reads JSON network config from SD card and passes the credentials into MQTT functions to connect to my broker. There is no bug, and the program is compiled with no issues. But for some reason, the MQTT connection keeps failing with the credentials read from the JSON file. When I manually assign the credentials, it runs normally again. I don't understand what the problem is here.
Here's the code: https://github.com/phamcongchung/ModbusRTU-Master-Log.git.
The function at line 392:
void getNetworkConfig(){
    File file = SD.open("/config.json");
    if (!file) {
        Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
        return;
    }
    // Allocate a JSON document
    StaticJsonDocument<128> config;
    // Parse the JSON from the file
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(config, file);
    if (error) {
        Serial.print("Failed to parse file: ");
        Serial.println(error.f_str());
        return;
    }
    file.close();
    JsonObject networkConfig = config["NetworkConfiguration"];
    apn = networkConfig["Apn"].as<const char*>(); Serial.println(apn);
    gprsUser = networkConfig["GprsUser"].as<const char*>(); Serial.println(gprsUser);
    gprsPass = networkConfig["GprsPass"].as<const char*>(); Serial.println(gprsPass);
    topic = networkConfig["Topic"].as<const char*>(); Serial.println(topic);
    broker = networkConfig["Broker"].as<const char*>(); Serial.println(broker);
    clientID = networkConfig["ClientId"].as<const char*>(); Serial.println(clientID);
    brokerUser = networkConfig["BrokerUser"].as<const char*>(); Serial.println(brokerUser);
}


"When I manually assign the credentials" - Do you mean that you still pass them by MQTT, just not fetch them from the file?

@johnnyaug yes, meaning I assign them at their declaration as const

Is there a missing password? The code in the question only sets a brokerUser but no brokerPassword

@hardillb No, the user in context does not require password

Change the credentials type to String, then use c_str() to convert them to char.
// GPRSS credentials
String apn;
String gprsUser;
String gprsPass;
// MQTT credentials
String topic;
String broker;
String clientID;
String brokerUser;
String brokerPass;

Example:
modem.gprsConnect(apn.c_str(), gprsUser.c_str(), gprsPass.c_str())
mqtt.setServer(broker.c_str(), port)

